# Ruby on Rails value by association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, haml

I have this freeform SQL that when run returns the name of a product, name of the associate attribute and the value for that attribute. What I am trying to work out is how I can use the with Ruby on Rails and Active Record

Freeform Query

```
select menu_items.name, menu_attributes.name, menu_attributes_items.menu_attribute_value from menu_attributes, menu_items, menu_attributes_items, venues
where menu_items.id = menu_attributes_items.menu_item_id
and menu_attributes.id = menu_attributes_items.menu_attribute_id
and venues.id = menu_attributes_items.venue_id
and menu_attributes.name = 'Price'
```

This is my current HAMl Template, though it only returns a list of the attributes i.e. Price, Size and not the values like the SQL does

```
    - for item in @venue.menu_items
  .grid-content
    .card
      = image_tag("drinks/#{item.name.titlecase.tr(' ','-')}.png")
      %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/400x200?text=Coffee"}
        .card-divider
          = item.name
        .card-section
          %h4
            - for attr in item.menu_attributes
              = attr.name
              = MenuItem.joins({ menu_attributes: :menu_attributes_items }, :venues).where('menu_items.id = menu_attributes_items.menu_item_id AND menu_attributes.id = menu_attributes_items.menu_attribute_id AND menu_attributes.id = menu_attributes_items.menu_attribute_id AND venues.id = menu_attributes_items.venue_id AND menu_attributes.name = ?', 'Price').select('menu_items.name, menu_attributes.name, menu_attributes_items.menu_attribute_value')
```

Updates
Price # Size # Size #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the associations among your models and still with a slight touch of SQL, your query can be written with ActiveRecord this way:

```
MenuItem.joins({ menu_attributes: :menu_attributes_items }, :venues)
    .where('menu_items.id = menu_attributes_items.menu_item_id AND menu_attributes.id = menu_attributes_items.menu_attribute_id AND menu_attributes.id = menu_attributes_items.menu_attribute_id AND venues.id = menu_attributes_items.venue_id AND menu_attributes.name = ?', 'Price')
    .select('menu_items.name, menu_attributes.name, menu_attributes_items.menu_attribute_value')
```

Comment: i can't use this directly within my html template though, everything else works apart from displaying the value

Comment: Could you please elaborate this: `everything else works apart from displaying the value` a bit? It's just active record query, you can embed this in your html/haml, also you can put this in your corresponding controller's action in an instance variable, and then access that in your view. Let me know which part is not working and how are you trying to do that.

Comment: wasn't aware you could embed a query into the haml file

Comment: so that query displays the hash but not the value

Comment: Can you please update your post with your latest code and how the output looks like now?

Comment: So, the query will give you a collection of results, you still need to loop through them and show them as per your need in your view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93295/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-paul-whippet-mcguane).